# How to get right link (permalink) to a exact wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a website that is a custom PHP site hosted at http://mysite.com. Then I have a Wordpress instance running on sub-domain at http://blog.mysite.com, where some post can be at URL http://blog.mysite.com/this-is-my-test-post-entry

In landing page of mysite.com I connect to Wordpress DB and fetch out last 5 entries from wp_posts table and show them on my home page. The problem is I don't know how to get the right links to those posts? Wordpress generates permalinks() but I don't know how to get them?

I thought Wordpress takes post title string and replaces spaces with "-" and uses that string for post URL. But doesn't work for all posts...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Request all of the post-row fields (*) from the database and var_dump them. It should be in there IIRC. It's a full URL.

Comment: Hi hakre. Tried that but link is not in any field... Looking ad wp_posts table I thought post_name filed is what I am looking, but  for some posts that is correct, but some not. Some posts have something like "17-revision-3" value in this field?!

Comment: That's the slug. It will become part of the URL. However the ID answer below is working always, so much more safe. WP will redirect the URLs to the correct one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it will work...

When you fetch your last 5 posts, get the id (make sure you're filtering on your post_type field to avoid grabbing things like revisions, attachments, etc).

You can simply build your URL like http://blog.mysite.com/?p=ID (where ID is the ID from the database).  WordPress will automatically redirect the user to the proper page with the custom permalink that you defined in your settings.

Let me know if you need a hand with the PHP.

Comment: Thanks. This worked but I am afraid it's not as SEO friendly as using full links... Still would love to find the solution with full links and not using PostID in query string.

Comment: I speculate that since WordPress is doing a permanent 301 redirect from the ?p=id version to the named permalink version that search engines will index the link using your named permalink.  I'm not a huge SEO expert, so I'm using an educated guess about that.

If you're feeling adventurous you can look at /wp-includes/rewrite.php. I didn't dig into it, but that's where they have the logic to transform your post name and permalink option to a url.  There's a function called "generate_rewrite_rules" with a comment saying, "... a mix of black magic and regular expressions" that made me smile.

Comment: You can as well fetch the RSS feed from your blog and use the data from that. Cache it for performance.

Comment: That is something I haven't thought about ... That should solve my problems!